# How to center whole bootstrap 3 page contents horizontally

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap 3 site pages content needs to centered horizontally if its width is smaller that bowser window width and in small zoom levels.

I tried to center whole page horizontally using

```
body {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

But content still appears in left side.

page content is inside bootstrap

```
<div class="containner-fluid">
```

element.
I tried to add fixed heightr using

```
.container-fluid {
    width: 1500px;
}
```

But content appear still in left side.
How to center content horizontally ?

Use mose wheel to decrease zoom level in chrome to minimum.
Content is still left-aligned, not in center of brower window.

Bootstrap3, jquery, jquery-ui, ASP.NET MVC3 are used

Comment: try changing the class .container-fluid to .container class then try to define the width of .container (e.g 720px) then add this 'margin: 0 auto; display: block;' to your .container class

Comment: fiddling with the default .container class taken from bootstrap is never a clean solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.container` instead of `.container-fluid`.

`.container-fluid` uses the full width.

> **[Bootstrap Containers](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container)**:
>
> Use `.container` for a responsive fixed width container.
>
> Use `.container-fluid` for a full width container, spanning the entire width of your viewport.

---

EDIT: As mentioned by [@SeRu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3899197/seru): Remove the body's `display: inline-block`

Answer (score 2):

remove `display: inline-block` from body and change `container-fluid to container`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display: inline-block;`

```
body {
   display: inline-block; //Remove it
    margin-left: auto; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set body size to 1500px
and change margin-right and margin-left to margin:0 auto; from container-fluid.
And remove your display: inline-block; from body.
[Screenshot of your website centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9mRq.png)